# Install Ubuntu but keep Local disk D and its content

Tags: installation, windows, windows-7, system-installation, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu and remove Windows 7. I choosed `Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu` option. Now it shows me which HDD disk to use and says that 3 partitions willbe deleted. But I need to install Ubuntu to Local Disk `C` and keep other local disk `D` and keep its content. WHat can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't click on Replace Ubuntu option.Just click on the something else option and select the partition(in your case it's `c`) then format it to ext4 filesystem.

Now install Ubuntu on the formatted partition.It doesn't affect other partitions.